# biblatex and German juristic commentaries

Tags: biblatex, citing, german

I need to get my manuscript ready for my publisher, and can't seem to get a few things fixed with `biblatex`. I'm using `biblatex` with the `biblatex-juradiss` style together with `jurabook` as a document class. The publisher wants to have a certain kind of publication in German jurisprudence, commentaries, to be typeset like this:

> MK-StGB-*Author* Edition § X Rn. Y

"MK-StGB" is the shorttitle, and § X Rn. Y are the references. Commentaries have multiple authors that comment on different parts of a law codex. Therefore I need to pass over the respective authors in the reference.

Here my code with an example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,compact,centeredpartsintoc,a4paper,fncontinued,12pt]{jurabook}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % Mac-Kodierung. Achtung: ≠ UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Damit Trennung besser klappen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Sprache
\usepackage{graphicx} % Zum Einbinden von Grafiken
\usepackage{soul} % Kapitälchen. Achtung: Bei UTF-8 -> soulutf8
\usepackage{times} % Ach ja, die Times
\usepackage{eurosym}
\setjbookstyle{partintro}{\LARGE}
\setjbookstyle{part}{\LARGE}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.4cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
uniquename=true,
sorting=nyvt,
sortcites=true,
maxnames=3,
idemtracker=false,
ibidtracker=false,
useprefix=false, %von an (true) oder aus (false)
style=biblatex-juradiss,safeinputenc]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literatur}
%\include{anpassungen_verlag} % Die Anpassungen für den Verlag
\begin{document}
Dies zielt normhistorisch wohl darauf ab, klarzustellen, dass kein Unternehmen
außerhalb des Anwendungsbereichs von Abs. 2 steht.\footnote{Siehe hierzu
\cite[Radtke][§ 14 Rn. 88]{mueko:band1}.}
\end{document}
```

And this is the commentary:

```
@commentary{mueko:band1,
    Date-Added = {2009-10-28 09:12:21 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2013-03-07 08:07:59 +0000},
    Edition = {2},
    Editor = {Heintschel-Heinegg, Bernd},
    Howcited = {MK-StGB-Bearbeiter},
    Publisher = {C.H. Beck},
    Shorttitle = {MK-StGB},
    Title = {M{\"u}nchener Kommentar zum Strafgesetzbuch},
    Volumetitle = {1 ({\S}{\S} 1-37)},
    Year = {2011}}
```

I don't get "Radtke" to appear behind the title, as I pass it over to `biblatex` in the prenote field. Can I somehow suppress the prenote field before the reference and put it behind the short title? Morevover, I don't seem to be able to get rid of all the commas after the author. Can anybody help or somehow put me on the right track? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. Most of the configuration that you’re providing doesn’t influence `biblatex` at all, as you will notice if you remove some of it and compile again. Please have a look at my answer to [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) to find out how to minimalize your sample here even further.

Comment: @doncherry People who are familiar with such questions won't care whether the MWE is minimal or not. The OP describes the issue clearly.

Comment: @Charlotte You probably won't get an answer here. I've been looking into this, it seems to be necessary to patch the file biblatex-juradiss.cbx As there is no maintainer of this file and the comments are in German, I suggest to ask at a list: TEX-D-L@LISTSERV.DFN.DE

Comment: @KeksDose I disagree and would point to myself as someone who does care. Also, I’ve never heard any mention of a kind of questions on tex.sx that doesn’t have to adhere to the same quality standards for MWEs as others.

Comment: Since the desired text doesn't match the example, I can't follow the question. Are you basically wanting for `@commentary` entrytypes the citation output: `<shorttitle>-<prenote> <edition> <postnote>`?

Comment: @Audrey The desired text meets the example, almost: OP wants MK-StGB-*Ratke* § 14 Rn. 88. I admit that "Edition" is missing in the example. But the trouble is to get *Ratke* printed after "MK-StGB".

Comment: @Audrey That's exactly what I mean! The edition would be nice, but the main problem and trouble is MK-StGB-_Radtke_ ... the "prenote" after the shorttitle! And: THANKS SO MUCH TO EVERYBODY!

Comment: @ KeksDose: Yes! <shorttitle>-<prenote> <edition> <postnote>

Comment: @Charlotte Please edit your question or give the answer yourself, I might be interested some day, how you put `\cite` correctly!

Answer (score 7):

Typically one can make entrytype-specific changes to existing citation commands via the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook. Unfortunately for your case this is too late because the hook is executed after any prenote is printed.

To get around this you can redefine the `prenote` bibliography macro. It appears that the juradiss style uses the default definition from `biblatex.def`:

```
\newbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}
```

Non-*ibidem* citation labels for `@commentary` entries are specified by the `cite:title` bibliography macro, which can be locally redefined to obtain the desired output. For an example add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro{prenote}{%
  \ifentrytype{commentary}
    {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}%
     \renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
       \printfield{labeltitle}%
       \setunit*{\textendash}%
       \printfield[emph]{prenote}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{edition}}}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\printfield{prenote}%
        \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}}
```

Comment: WOW! It works! It's exactly what I needed and such an intelligent and elegant solution! I thank you SO MUCH!! This was the last step towards the publication of my PhD-thesis and I owe it to you! MERCI!

Comment: @Charlotte Happy to help. Congratulations.