# biblatex-juradiss and german juristic commentaries

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I'm writing my master’s thesis and I'm having troubles formatting citations the way I need to. I've tried to modify the solution given in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102287/biblatex-and-german-juristic-commentaries) but without success.

I'm using `biblatex` with `biblatex-juradiss` in KOMA's class `scrbook`.

I need to cite as follow:

> Palandt/*Thorn*, Anh. Art. 10 EGBGB Rn 1

- Palandt (shorthand)
- *Thorn* (prenote)
- Anh. Art. 10 EGBGB (title)
- Rn 1 (postnote)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{kommentare.bib}

@COMMENTARY{palandt, gender = {pm}, editor = {Palandt, Otto}, editortype = {founder}, maintitle = {Beck'sche Kurz Kommentar: B{\"u}rgerliches Gesetzbuch}, title = {Anh. zu Art. 10}, shorthand = {Palandt}, volume = {7}, publisher = {C.H. Beck}, edition = {71}, location = {M{\"u}nchen}, Year = {2012}, keywords = {Kommentar}}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sortcites=true,style=biblatex-juradiss,sorting=nyt,safeinputenc]{biblatex}

\bibliography{kommentare}

\renewbibmacro{prenote}{%
  \ifentrytype{commentary}
    {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}%
     \renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
       \printfield{labeltitle}%
       \setunit*{\textendash}%
       \printfield[emph]{prenote}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{edition}}}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\printfield{prenote}%
        \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}}
\begin{document}
\cite[Thorn][Rn 1]{palandt}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Like I've said I've tried to edit the solution given in another thread but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution editing the aforementioned solution, it's probably a "dirty" one but it works.

```
            \documentclass{scrbook}

            \usepackage{filecontents}

            \begin{filecontents}{kommentare.bib}

            @COMMENTARY{palandt, gender = {pm}, editor = {Palandt, Otto}, editortype = {founder}, maintitle = {Beck'sche Kurz Kommentar: B{\"u}rgerliches Gesetzbuch}, title = {Anh. zu Art. 10}, shorthand = {Palandt}, volume = {7}, publisher = {C.H. Beck}, edition = {71}, location = {M{\"u}nchen}, Year = {2012}, keywords = {Kommentar}}

            \end{filecontents}

            \usepackage[backend=biber,sortcites=true,style=biblatex-juradiss,sorting=nyt,safeinputenc]{biblatex}

            \bibliography{kommentare}

            \DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{postnote}{Rn\addspace{#1}}

            % Kursive Schrift für Bearbeiter von Kommentaren
            \DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{prenote}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

            \DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand}{%
              \ifbool{bbx:shorthandacro}%
                {\ifbool{bbx:acronym}%
                  {\mkbibacro{#1}\isdot}%
                  {#1\isdot}}%
                {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{commentary} {#1\printfield[edition:super]{edition}}
                  {\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}%
                }%
            }% 


            \renewbibmacro{prenote}{%
              \ifentrytype{commentary}
                    {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}%
                 \renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
                   \printfield{shorthand}%
                   \setunit*{\addslash}%
                   \printfield{prenote}%
                   \setunit{\addspace}%
                   \printfield{title}}}
                {\iffieldundef{prenote}
                   {}
                   {\printfield{prenote}%
                    \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}}

            \begin{document}

            \cite[Thorn][1]{palandt}

            \printbibliography

            \end{document}
```

I hope this can help someone.