# Special style for commentary citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jurabib

I need to have a special citation style for commentaries in my thesis. I hope he following example illustrates the problem sufficiently:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, fleqn, pdftex, version=last, x11names,pointlessnmbers]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{ngerman, geometry, graphicx, keyval, ifpdf, ifvtex, placeins, nicefrac, abstract}
\geometry{a4paper, left=30mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
%howcited=all, 
%howcited=normal,
howcited=multiple,
authorformat=smallcaps,  
%bibformat=tabular,
authorformat=smallcaps,
]{jurabib}

\renewcommand{\bibtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibbtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibjtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibapifont}{\normalfont}
\AddTo\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\etalname}{\normalfont{\,et\,al.}}%
  \renewcommand{\editorsname}{\normalfont{(Hrsg.)}}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibaesep}{, }
\renewcommand{\bibbtasep}{/} % bta = between two authors sep
\renewcommand{\bibbfsasep}{/} 
\renewcommand{\bibbstasep}{/}
\renewcommand{\bibbtesep}{/} % bte = between two editors sep
\renewcommand{\bibbfsesep}{/} % bfse = between first and second editor sep
\renewcommand{\bibbstesep}{/}
\renewcommand{\bibbtsep}{in: }
\renewcommand{\bibjtsep}{in: }
\renewcommand{\bibleftcolumn}{6cm} 
\renewcommand{\bibrightcolumn}{\textwidth-\bibleftcolumn-0.6cm}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightcolumnadjust}{}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand{\editionname}{Aufl.}}
\renewcommand{\bibansep}{: }
\renewcommand{\bibatsep}{,}
\renewcommand{\bibbdsep}{}
\renewcommand{\bibatsep}{,} 
\renewcommand{\biburlprefix}{\jblangle{}}
\renewcommand{\biburlsuffix}{\jbrangle{}}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\urldatecomment}{zuletzt abgerufen am }}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\howcitedprefix}{ (zit.: }} 
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\howcitedsuffix}{)}} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\jbaensep}{,}
\renewcommand*{\jbhowsepbeforetitle}{,~}
\makeatletter
\jb@allow@howcited@art@periodtrue
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\biblnfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\bibfnfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\bibefnfont}{\scshape} %format editor first name
\renewcommand{\bibelnfont}{\scshape} %format editor last name

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\section{Section to illustrate the problem}
Here ist how the commentary should be quoted in the bibliography:\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{Mustermann, Max} (Hrsg.), Zürcher Kommentar, 5. Aufl., Zürich 2013 (zit. ZK - \textsc{Bearbeiter}, Art. N Rn. N)\\[1cm]
And thats how the citation has to look like:\\[0.5cm]
ZK - \textsc{Bearbeiter}, Art. 500 Rn. 3.\\[1cm]
And this is how it looks like right now\footnote{vgl. \cite[Bearbeiter][Art. 500. Rn. 3.]{ZK}}.

\end{document}
```

```
@commented{ZK,    
    Date-Added = {2013-10-12 15:40:02 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2013-10-12 15:42:11 +0200},
    Editor = {Max Mustermann},
    Howcited = {ZK},
    Publisher = {Z{\"u}rich},
    Shorttitle = {ZK},
    Title = {Z{\"u}rcher Kommentar},
    Year = {2013}}
```

Comment: I'm afraid some parts of your question are not exactly clear to me. Could you add a MWE including a `.bib` entry and a short sample use of the cite command?

Comment: Apparently, there are ways this can be done satisfyingly with `biblatex` (`biblatex-juradiss`), see [`biblatex-juradiss` and German juristic commentaries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105794/35864) and [`biblatex` and German juristic commentaries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102287/35864). If you want a `jurabib` solution though, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) would be very much appreciated. (You have done quite a bit of research yourself, it would be very helpful to see the *actual code* for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jurbib` implements an `author` (`title` if necessary to disambiguate more works by the same author(s)) citation style, while you seem to favour a `title` style, so `jurabib` might not be the best choice after all.

The separator between the comment and the commenting author is easily changed by `\DeclareRobustCommand{\jbhowsepannotatorlast}{ -- }%`.

To get the shorthand for the commentary instead of the author/editor, the easiest way seems to be to put the commentary title into the `shortauthor` field, like so:

```
@commented{ZK,    
  Editor = {Max Mustermann},
  Publisher = {Z{\"u}rich},
  Shorttitle = {ZK},
  Shortauthor = {ZK}, % this is new (and quite an abuse of the shortauthor field)
  Title = {Z{\"u}rcher Kommentar},
  Year = {2013}}
```

Normally, `jurabib` uses the `author`/`editor` to cite a work, not the `title`, so we abuse the `shortauthor` field.

There seems to be no sensible way to get the "Art. 500 Rn. 3" stuff in the bibliography, however, but it does not seems to make too much sense: one would not say "cited as Knuth 1986, p. 5" in the bibliography.

To get a comma between the citation and the page use the package option `commabeforerest=true,`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  howcited=multiple,
  authorformat=smallcaps,  
  commabeforerest=true,
]{jurabib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@commented{ZK,    
  Editor = {Max Mustermann},
  Publisher = {Z{\"u}rich},
  Shorttitle = {ZK},
  Shortauthor = {ZK},
  Title = {Z{\"u}rcher Kommentar},
  Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\bibtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibbtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibjtfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bibapifont}{\normalfont}
\AddTo\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\etalname}{\normalfont{\,et\,al.}}%
  \renewcommand{\editorsname}{\normalfont{(Hrsg.)}}%
}
\renewcommand{\bibaesep}{, }
\renewcommand{\bibbtasep}{/} % bta = between two authors sep
\renewcommand{\bibbfsasep}{/} 
\renewcommand{\bibbstasep}{/}
\renewcommand{\bibbtesep}{/} % bte = between two editors sep
\renewcommand{\bibbfsesep}{/} % bfse = between first and second editor sep
\renewcommand{\bibbstesep}{/}
\renewcommand{\bibbtsep}{in: }
\renewcommand{\bibjtsep}{in: }
\renewcommand{\bibleftcolumn}{6cm} 
\renewcommand{\bibrightcolumn}{\textwidth-\bibleftcolumn-0.6cm}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightcolumnadjust}{}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand{\editionname}{Aufl.}}
\renewcommand{\bibansep}{: }
\renewcommand{\bibatsep}{,}
\renewcommand{\bibbdsep}{}
\renewcommand{\bibatsep}{,} 
\renewcommand{\biburlprefix}{\jblangle{}}
\renewcommand{\biburlsuffix}{\jbrangle{}}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\urldatecomment}{zuletzt abgerufen am }}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\howcitedprefix}{ (zit.: }} 
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\renewcommand*{\howcitedsuffix}{)}} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\jbaensep}{,}
\renewcommand*{\jbhowsepbeforetitle}{,~}
\makeatletter
\jb@allow@howcited@art@periodtrue
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\biblnfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\bibfnfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\bibefnfont}{\scshape} %format editor first name
\renewcommand{\bibelnfont}{\scshape} %format editor last name


\DeclareRobustCommand{\jbhowsepannotatorlast}{ -- }%

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\section{Section to illustrate the problem}
Here ist how the commentary should be quoted in the bibliography:\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{Mustermann, Max} (Hrsg.), Zürcher Kommentar, 5. Aufl., Zürich 2013 (zit. ZK - \textsc{Bearbeiter}, Art. N Rn. N)\\[1cm]
And thats how the citation has to look like:\\[0.5cm]
ZK - \textsc{Bearbeiter}, Art. 500 Rn. 3.\\[1cm]
And this is how it looks like right now\footnote{vgl. \cite[Bearbeiter][Art. 500. Rn. 3.]{ZK}}.

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

---

What you want seems to be easily - and more semantically correctly - implementable in [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (with [`biblatex-juradiss`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-juradiss), you can find the [`biblatex-juradiss` documentation here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-juradiss/biblatex-juradiss.pdf)), see [`biblatex` and German juristic commentaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102287/35864).